# Change leftmark in header only for ToC

Tags: overleaf

I am using a template from my University in Overleaf and have a cosmetic issue:

Here is a MWE (tested in Overleaf):

```
\documentclass[openright,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhead{} 
  \fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
  \fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
  \fancyfoot{} 
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt} 

\fontsize{11pt}{15pt}\selectfont
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\bfseries\fontsize{19}{25}\selectfont}{\thechapter\quad}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries\fontsize{13}{17}\selectfont}{\thesection\quad}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries\fontsize{11}{15}\selectfont}{\thesubsection\quad}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\bfseries\fontsize{9}{13}\selectfont}{\thesubsubsection\quad}{0pt}{}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\normalfont\bfseries Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Introduction}
\newpage
test
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\chapter{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}
\section{test}

\chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

The ToC is more than one page long and therefore, the second page of the ToC gets a fancy header showing in the left upper corner the title "Table of Contents". I have adjusted the font and name of the ToC title to use normalfont and bfseries, therefore this title in the header is also bold. But I would like to be it like on page 4 (so not bold).

I read about changing the chaptermark, but it is only necessary for the ToC and not all chapters, therefore I don't know how to do this. Is this even possible?

I know that the code is quite ugly as there are a lot of work arounds because of that ugly template I have to use. And if this is impossible then I will live with the bold chaptermark in the ToC. I was just wondering if this would be possible.

Here are two pictures explaining the matter.

Bold chaptermark in ToC
[image]

And not bold chaptermark in Introduction
[image]

**Edit regarding Ulrike's suggestion**

`\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\normalfont\bfseries Table of Contents}`
[image]
I want this font

`\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}`
[image]

**Edit problem SOLVED**

`\usepackage[titles]{titlesec}` solved my issue

Comment: Use only `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}`. This command should not contain formatting instructions.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes that would solve my problem. But then the font is different. I edited my post to show you want I mean. I want the font of the first picture, but with your suggestion I get the other font.

Comment: If you also add the `titles` option when loading tocloft: `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`, the "Table of Contents" heading should then be the same as normal chapters.

Comment: well you get quite loud warnings in the log that titlesec, titletoc and scrreprt are not compatible (assuming that you have a rather current tex system. I would remove all the packages and do the font setup with the tool of scrreprt.

Comment: @imnothere Yes! That solved my issue! Thank you very much!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes that would be the best solution, but I need to use this damn template... Therefore the really ugly code. But imnothere has solved my issue!